# Trouble opening CSV file in QGIS with Delimited Text plugin

Tags: qgis, csv

I am trying to open a **CSV** file in QGIS using the **Delimited Text plugin**. I’m working with **Windows 8** and **QGIS 2.18.1**.

My CSV file  has around **4.000 points** to be plotted, but when I try to open it from QGIS it **only shows the first 20 lines**. Those 20 lines are perfect but I have no idea why the rest of my csv wont open.

Look at this picture of the **Delimited Text window** to check if im doing everything right.

[image]

Also, here is a part of my csv file, showing the last line read by the QGIS (I dont know how to upload the file, so I sent a prntScr)

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Is it possible to see the csv, or portion of it that is greater than 20 rows?

Comment: Ok, I added the first part of the file..